# when i change my button to an icon i can't click on it to go to a new layout

Tags: android, xml, button, icons

this my xml file main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@raw/christmas"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/by_kostas"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="83dp"
        android:text="@string/by_kostas" 
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#F2F3F4"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="nameOfMethod"
        android:src="@raw/settings" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my java Main

```
     package com.kostas.mytorch; 
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.ImageView;


        public class Main extends Activity {

                @Override
                 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    //start our layout
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.main);{

                    final ImageView diskView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.settings);

                    diskView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View v){
                            //my codes
                       }
                    });

                    diskView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v){
                            // System.out.println("image clicked...");//in my logcat

                            startActivity(new Intent("com.kostas.standroid.settings"));
                        }
                     });

                }
        }
```

my problem is when i click in the settings icon, my program crashes instead of what i wanted to create a new layout (settings xml is just black page),can someone be kind enough to help me out

Comment: start the activity from some valid context - Main.this.startActivit(...)

Comment: Please provide crash log. Btw your settings activity is existing? Also you declared it in the manifest.xml ? Where is your "nameOfMethod" in the java file ? You declared in the xml...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach click listener to any `view` by two ways:

1. In xml, write `onClick` attribute of the view and pass the method
   name you have implemented in the activity.

Example: android:onClick="someMethod" and in the activity code, declare a method

```
public void someMethod(View view)
{
    // handle click here
}
```

1. In activity, use `setOnClickListener()` to the view.

For now, try this:

```
diskView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v){
                            // System.out.println("image clicked...");//in my logcat

                            startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, settings.class));
                    }
                 });
```

Also remove this line from xml: `android:onClick="nameOfMethod"`

Comment: just one last thing,what should i exactly do with settings.class cause it doesn't accept as a type

Comment: @user3065448 try changing class name to start with Capital letter. Please follow naming conventions while coding.

Comment: @user3065448 Does the files `Main.java` and `settings.java` lie in the same package ?

Answer (score 0):

Some time there is contextual problem. Try this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, UpcomingActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Also don't forget to define class in Manifest file

Answer (score 0):

try to remove

```
android:onClick="nameOfMethod"
```

from the xml layout. I believe this is the method that it's called when you click the settings button and it doesn't exist so it crashes.